# Thumbnail Grid Control like Windows Explorer

Tags: wpf, gridview, wpf-controls, thumbnails

I'm looking for a free WPF control that can show a gird like windows explorer's thumbnail new, rows of images with some info under each thumb, it would be added benefit if it could be switched to detail and list view too but for now the thumbnail view is the most important,

I'm not that familiar with WPF's built-in controls so this might very well exist in the framework (this is my first WPF project)

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484293/wpf-listview-with-icons-view) StackOverflow topic can help you.