# Display Different Views (Thumbnail,Details List) in Wpf from ListView in MVVM

Tags: wpf, listview, mvvm

I have a DataGrid that is displaying Data. I want to implement view switching functionality in WPF. I have read online and they say it's not possible with Data Grid .

There is also a topic that explains thumbnail view:

[WPF: ListView with icons view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484293/wpf-listview-with-icons-view)

But how to implement the same three view in the same control?

To be exact, I want the functionality like Windows Explorer where we can change the view from a dropdown list.

Some help in this regard would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right. This is not something that the `DataGrid` supports. You can create your own views for the `ListView`, see the following article:

[How to: Create a Custom View Mode for a ListView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748859.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. I am Using BureauBlue.xaml Theme form WPF codeplex site... bucause of which i am not able to use Custom view inside a ListView i can only show data if i use a GridView and then assign a cell template i cant remove the theme as its used in the application.... Not data is populated if i use the above method in my project

Comment: is there ne way to overide that behaviour