# Flow icon view in WPF ListView

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, listview

I am new to WPF and as a learning project I opted for a Windows Explorer like File Manager. In this project I want to display the the List view as a icon list that follows flow layout pattern. I tried the solutions given here: [WPF: ListView with icons view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484293/wpf-listview-with-icons-view). But they are making my icons overlap each other. My icons are basically user controls that are loaded dynamically. This is my code for user control that represents a list view icon:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MVCP.FileItem"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" Height="156.767" Width="161.279">
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Image HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="100" Margin="10,10,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="141" Source="fileflat.png"/>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,120,10,5" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="&lt;Filename&gt;" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="32" Width="141" FontSize="18" Foreground="White" TextAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And this is my ListView code:

```
<ListView x:Name="files" Background="#FF19174B" AllowDrop="True" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="files_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" MouseMove="files_MouseMove">
    <local:FileItem/>
    <local:FileItem/>
    <local:FileItem/>
    <local:FileItem/>
</ListView>
```

How can I arrange these user controls so that they can look like Windows Explorer icons?

Comment: have you tried using panels inside `ListView` ?

Comment: Thanks @AbinMathew you gave me a hint and I tried it. It worked. See my answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

@AbinMathew gave me a hint for using Panels. So, I changed my code like this and it worked. :)

```
<ListView x:Name="files" Background="#FF19174B" AllowDrop="True" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="files_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" MouseMove="files_MouseMove">
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <DockPanel>
                <local:FileItem/>
            </DockPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <local:FileItem/>
    <local:FileItem/>
    <local:FileItem/>
    <local:FileItem/>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding any `panel` inside your `ListView`

```
<ListView x:Name="files" Background="#FF19174B" AllowDrop="True" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="files_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" MouseMove="files_MouseMove">
 <StackPanel>
   <local:FileItem/>
   <local:FileItem/>
   <local:FileItem/>
   <local:FileItem/>
 </StackPanel>
</ListView>
```

Comment: This is not the right way, the meaning of you've written is "having a single object inside the listview whose elements are 4 local:FileItem".
Most probably what you'd like to do was to set "ListView.ItemsPanel" as @Aishwarya has done. Nonetheless, using the "StackPanel" wouldn't let you go to next line, but ... instead ... widening the ListView (in the best option) or cutting out some of your FileItem.

Comment: @FabioDch as per the question asked by SO i just give a hint what went wrong in there code, and yeah i didnt made the effort to make it dynamic thats correct but as per what SO asked i answered it. and yeah you too have option to edit my answer to make it more valuable.